# How to read the file name while reading the files from s3 using pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I have a usecase, have mutltiple files in s3 which I am reading like this:

```
df1 = spark.read.csv("s3://bucket/fact/*.dat")
```

all of the .dat files have 6 digits at the start which is PO id

```
190234_purcahse.dat
125134_purcahse.dat
```

This PO id I need in the dataframe df1 as a new column while reading. How can I achieve this in most efficient way?
Is there any way to to get the file name while reading the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [**`input_file_name()`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/#input_file_name) function from spark.

```
df1 = spark.read.csv("s3://bucket/fact/*.dat").withColumn("fn",input_file_name())
```

Then use **`regexp_extract()`** function to extract your PO id.